# QMYSQL3 unable to reset statement

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt5 execute `submitAll()` multiple times,the error occurred.

```
void UserManageWork::submitAll()
{
    bool res = true;
    DB.open();
    res = relTableModel->submitAll();   //QSqlRelationalTableModel
    DB.close();
    emit submitAllFinished(res);
}
```

It does not occur the first, but often the second.

---

The QSqlRelationalTableModel is loaded using the child thread, it does not work in the ui thread, I may now know why the error occurs, as @chehrlic said, there is an open QSqlQuery in QSqlRelationalTableModel, I should not execute DB.close() at this point.

My question now is, if I want to use QSqlRelationalTableModel in the child thread and load the model with tableview through the signal-slot, how should I manage the opening and closing of the database connection in the child thread.

Comment: Please provide a (minimal, reproducible example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] of your program. Also the calls to DB.open() & close() look fishy since you **must not** close a db connection when a QSqlQuery is still active on it but it is in your case - QSqlRelationalTableModel has an open QSqlQuery,

Comment: I agree with @chehrlic, you should not be opening and closing the connection to the database when using the model which needs a connection to the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @chehrlic, I may now know why the error occurs. if I want to use QSqlRelationalTableModel in the child thread and load the model with tableview through the signal-slot, how should I manage the database connection in the child thread(When to open, when to close, and what if the database connection is disconnected due to a timeout).

Comment: This is currently not supported as you can't move a database connection around in other threads.